# Correct path to store photos from Cam?

Tags: android, camera, store

I'm currently developing a WebCam app, which basically stores a picture in a defined time period (like one photo per minute). If for some reason the upload to an external web server fails, I want to temporarily store that photo in the file system.

Is there any convention about where to store those temporary files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.  It's described in [the data storage document in the dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).  You're probably especially interested in the Internal Storage and External Storage sections.